# Convert a list of maps into a nested map in groovy

Tags: groovy, hashmap

I have a list of maps;

```
b = [{key1=hello, key2=world}, {key1=hello2, key2=world2}, {key1=hello3, key2=world3}, {key1=hello4, key2=world4}]
```

How do I convert this into something like this?

```
b = [{key1=hello, key2=world, {key1=hello2, key2=world2, {key1=hello3, key2=world3, {key1=hello4, key2=world4}}}}]
```

Comment: any code you tried already?

Comment: The 2nd `b` is NOT a map

Comment: Sorry, I am new to groovy. I didn't try anything yet.

Comment: Add injecteer says, `b` is not a valid map, it's sort of half way between a map and a list... What exactly do you want for output?

Answer (score 0):

```
def a=[[key1:'hello', key2:'world'], [key1:'hello2', key2:'world2'], [key1:'hello3', key2:'world3']]

def b=a.reverse().inject(null){prev,item->
    item.next = prev
    return item
}

println new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(b).toPrettyString()
```

output:

```
{
    "key1": "hello",
    "key2": "world",
    "next": {
        "key1": "hello2",
        "key2": "world2",
        "next": {
            "key1": "hello3",
            "key2": "world3",
            "next": null
        }
    }
}
```